# Change keyboard's language with ADB?

Tags: adb, settings

I know there is a way to detect the current `enabled_input_methods`:

```
settings get secure enabled_input_methods
com.samsung.android.honeyboard/.service.HoneyBoardService;65538;2621440:com.samsung.android.svoiceime/.SamsungVoiceReco:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.ime.VoiceInputMethodService
```

Also, there is a way to get the current default:

```
settings get secure default_input_method
com.samsung.android.honeyboard/.service.HoneyBoardService
```

I'm using Samsung Keyboard, and those two numbers: 65538 and 2621440 seems to be the current languages enabled.

Moreover, the first one of them seems to be the default, because if I change the language, they will change their positions.

However, I can't seem to change `enabled_input_methods` via ADB, because my setting is not being stored:

```
settings put secure enabled_input_methods 'com.samsung.android.honeyboard/.service.HoneyBoardService;2621440;65538:com.samsung.android.svoiceime/.SamsungVoiceReco:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.ime.VoiceInputMethodService'
```

Here I changed those two numbers, but it stays the same:

```
settings get secure enabled_input_methods
com.samsung.android.honeyboard/.service.HoneyBoardService;65538;2621440:com.samsung.android.svoiceime/.SamsungVoiceReco:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.ime.VoiceInputMethodService
```

Can I somehow do this?